# Need to check how much memory my hash table has taken after inserting 1 million key values

Tags: c, hashmap, string-hashing, weakhashmap

I am using `khash.h` library for hashing. I want to check how much memory it has consumed after inserting my 1 million keys.

Here is the code.

https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/blob/master/khash.h

What I want: I am entering n unique entry in this table. and after inserting key and value I want to check how much space this hastable is consuming.

Issue: Example after entering 1000 entry. When I try to get the size of hashtable using `kh_size(h)` function given in `khash.h` I am getting 387 entries only. But when I am trying get the value by giving the key I am able to get.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "khash.h"
#include "string.h"

#define kh_get_val(kname, hash, key, defVal) ({k=kh_get(kname, hash, key);(k!=kh_end(hash)?kh_val(hash,k):defVal);})
#define kh_set(kname, hash, key, val) ({int ret; k = kh_put(kname, hash,key,&ret); kh_value(hash,k) = val; ret;})

const int khIntInt = 33;

KHASH_MAP_INIT_INT(khIntInt, long long) // setup khash to handle string key with int payload

int int_key_int_body_example(char *filename) {
    printf("\n\nBegin khash test string key with int payload\n");
    int ret, is_missing;
    khiter_t k;
    char *tval;
    khash_t(khIntInt) *h = kh_init(khIntInt); // create a hashtable
    printf("\n --------------------------------- FILE READ AND WRITE OPERTAION -------------------\n");

    FILE *fp;
    int * ch;
    char line[200];
    fp = fopen(filename,"r");
    if (!fp) {
        perror("could not find the file");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("\n ------------------------------------------------- PUTTING ALL KEYS ---------------------\n");

    int count = 0;
    long long val_line = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 200, fp) != NULL ) {
        printf(" Trying to Add key = %s and value = %s count =%lu \n",
               line, line, count++);
        val_line = strtoll(line, NULL, 0);
        printf("\n int_key_int_body: Here is the value in integer After Atoi = %ld \n", val_line);
        kh_set(khIntInt, h, val_line, val_line);
        printf(" ### DEBUG: h->n_buckets=%d,h->size=%d,h->n_occupied=%d,h->upper_bound=%d \n ",
               h->n_buckets, h->size, h->n_occupied, h->upper_bound);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("\n ------------------------------------------------- GETTING ALL VALUES ---------------------\n");
    count = 0;
    while (fgets(line, 200, fp) != NULL) {
        val_line = strtoll(line, NULL, 0);
        printf("\n int_key_int_body: Here is the value in integer After Atoi = %ld \n",val_line);
        k = kh_get(khIntInt, h, val_line);
        if (k == kh_end(h)) {
            printf("no key found for line=%ld", val_line);
        } else {
            printf("GET value for  key = %s and value = %d count =%lu and k_iterator=%d \n",
                   line, kh_val(h, k), count++, k);
        }
    }
    printf("\n ------------------------------------------------- ---------------------\n");
    kh_destroy(khIntInt, h);
    return 0;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *filename;
    filename = argv[1];
    printf("\n filename=%s", filename);
    int_key_int_body_example(filename);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for info. I have changed my question.